# Hibernate sessions REST performance/security

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, session, rest

### Intro

I'm bulding a REST web service using Hibernate and Jersey to supply JSON data to mobile clients. I have a general question about **how to deal with Hibernate sessions internally**. There are two different approaches(A,B) I'd like to discuss.

### Approaches

**A.** Someone told me I should open a new session per user, let it open for the whole web session of the user and finally close this session after the user stopped using my web service. I was told it would be a better approach from the view of security and performance.

Though I've read that:

```
"Sessions are irrelevant" Common REST Mistakes, 6.
```

**B.** Right now I'm using a SessionFactory to open a session in my service classes and close this session immediately after a query is done. My web service is only using GET and POST requests. There is not PUT or DELETE. I don't need any user authentication (like oAuth) to request data. Therefore I don't think it's necessary to use Transactions

#### Here is an Example of my Service class:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction(); 

Query query = session.createQuery("from RoomEntity");   
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<RoomEntity> list = (List<RoomEntity>) query.list();

session.close();
```

### Questions

Would be great to hear your opinion about my following questions:

1. What would be the best practice? Which approach do you follow?
2. What do you think about the performance matter?
3. What do you think about the security matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like A. It makes your service stateful and how do you know when a user has finished with your services anyway?

The general rule with Hibernate and web apps is to use a **single session per http request**. Most REST service GET requests map pretty simply to a single DB query as you have demonstrated with B, so this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should be having one Session per request, its called Onit of Work pattern. There are frameworks out there that support this implementation one of them is Spring(I would recomend to use it and not try to reinvent a wheel). You can read about it [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation. Based on the [JBOSS documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request) a session per request within Jersey appears to be valid. You could use an implementation of the ContainerRequestFilter in Jersey to open up a hibernate session and then close it with commits in an implementation of the ContainerResponseFilter.